# Goodness-of-fit test when the sample space is monotonically increasing

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I came across this [paper](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/48/1-2/109/225627?redirectedFrom=fulltext) which develops a GoF test on data drawn from a circular sample space (i.e. it has cyclical support).

I am now wondering if there is a parallel to monotonic supports (or if such a GoF test exists at all)? I.e. one in which there is a rank-ordering on the sample space.

**What is the point of all of this?**

I am looking at measuring the GOF on discrete observed data that is monotonically increasing. So this is not the usual case unfortunately since most GOF tests are not designed for discrete data (lots of fascinating papers on this). So suppose you have one hypothetical model that looks like a staircase (i.e. monotonically increasing) and you have another measured dataset that is discrete, and looks roughly like a staircase; is there a test which can measure the GOF?

Comment: Do you mean real, continuous data, or positive data? That is the usual case, so should not need anything special. ;aybe you need to be much more specific. Tell us the context!

Comment: Certainly! I am looking at measuring the GOF on discrete observed data that is monotonically increasing. So this is not the usual case at all unfortunately since most GOF tests are not designed for discrete data (lots of fascinating papers on this). So suppose you have one hypothetical model that looks like a staircase (i.e. monotonically increasing) and you have another measured dataset that is discrete, and looks roughly like a staircase; is there a test which can measure the GOF?

Comment: Can you please add this new information as an edit to the question? Few people read comments ...

Comment: Have upated the question now

Comment: I don't know what it means for a sample space to be monotonically increasing (or that a model 'looks like a staircase') - could you post an example?